# Inserting a node at nth position

Tags: c, linked-list

```
node* insertnth(struct node_q* list,int ndex,struct node_q* qtemp){//temp is the node to be inserted at the back of ndex
    struct node_q* temp;
    struct node_q* curr;
    int i;
    temp = list;
    curr = temp;
    for(i=0;i<=ndex;i++){
        if(temp!=NULL)
        temp = temp->pnext;
    }
        curr = temp;
        temp = temp->pnext;
        curr->pnext = NULL;
        curr->pnext = qtemp;
        qtemp->pnext = temp;

        return list;
}
```

I dont have an idea why it crashes. this function should insert the node temp at the back of the index or after the index and reconnects it to the list all the pointer of the struct are set to null before passing as parameter  except for the list it has already nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really trying to insert at the `n`th position in the normal meaning, you're off by one.  Inserting at position `n` normally means the new item is at the `n`th position *after* insertion.  In C, `n` starts at zero. So inserting at the `0`th position puts the new item at the head of the list.  Inserting at the `L`th, where `L` is the original list length, puts it last.

Even if you fixed your off-by-1 mistake, the code is confused and ugly.

This problem gets easier if you think in terms of advancing two pointers down the list: a "lead" and "trail" pointer.  The trail starts as NULL with the lead pointing at the list head.  Advance the pair `n` times.

Iterating the lead and trail pointers is possible with a nice `for` loop idiom:

```
int i;
struct node *lead, *trail;

for (i = 0, trail = NULL, lead = list; 
     i < n && lead != NULL; 
     ++i, trail = lead, lead = lead->next)
```

After that's done, there are two cases. The most common is that `lead` and `trail` are pointing respectively at `n`th and `n-1`th list items, where the lead might be NULL (i.e. you've reached the end of the list). In this case, inserting the new node is just:

```
new_node->next = lead;
trail->next = new_node;
return list;
```

The other case is that `trail` is still pointing at NULL. That means `n` was zero.  In this case the code above won't work.  The second line will fail.  Here you just want to make the new node the new list head:

```
new_node->next = lead; 
return new_node;
```

I will let you put the pieces together. You ought to get something small and beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

```
curr = temp;
        temp = temp->pnext;
        curr->pnext = NULL;
        curr->pnext = qtemp;
        qtemp->pnext = temp;
```

even in this code you access `temp->pnext` so it should not be NULL.

```
    if(temp!=NULL)
    {
    curr = temp;
    temp = temp->pnext;
    curr->pnext = NULL;
    curr->pnext = qtemp;
    qtemp->pnext = temp;
    }
    else
    {
       printf("wrong index");
    }
```

And if you are starting indexing at 1 then better change the loop condition to insert the node at indexed position,

```
for(i=0;i<ndex;i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value you provide for ndex is greater than or equal to (current number of nodes in the list)-1 you will attempt to dereference a null pointer and get a segfault.  Consider a list with 3 nodes in it and an ndex value of 2 input to the function:

list-->node 0-->node 1-->node 2-->NULL

- Starting condition:

  - temp = node 0
  - curr = node 0
  - ndex = 2
- First iteration of the for loop:

  - i = 0, 0 <= 2
  - temp != NULL, assign temp = node 0->next (node 1)
- Second iteration:

  - i = 1, 1 <= 2
  - temp != NULL, assign temp = node 1->next (node 2)
- Third iteration:

  - i = 2, 2 <= 2
  - temp != NULL, assign temp = node 2->next (NULL)
- Post-loop operations:

  - assign curr = temp (NULL)
  - assign temp = temp->next (dereferences NULL pointer and crashes)

So really there are two problems with your code:

- The insertion is not happening at the correct location because you're mixing indexing conventions.  Your index value input to the function and the conditional in the for loop act as though the list is indexed from 1, but the starting condition of the for loop acts as though the list is indexed from 0
- The code is not checking whether the iteration has reached the end of the list before attempting the insertion.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public void Insert (Type object, int k, bool flag) 
{ 
      Flag = false; 
      ListNode<Type> current = head; 
      bool found = false; 

       while ((current.next != null)&&(found == false)) 
     { 
    if(current.data == obiect) 
        found = true;   else 
        current = current.next; 
     } 
    If (found) 
            System.out.println(“The object already in the List”);    else 
        { 
            if (k > n) 
    { 
        ListNode<Type> newNode = new ListNode<Type>(); 
        newNode.data = object;          newNode.next = null; 
        current.next = newNode;         tail =newNode 
              } 
    else if(k <= 1) 
    { 
        ListNode<Type> newNode = new ListNode<Type>(); 
        newNode.data = object; 
        newNode.next = head.next;       head =newNode 

    } 
    else  
    { 
        int i = 1; 
        current = head; 
        while((I == k)&&(current.next != null)) 
        { 
            current = current.next; 
            i++; 
        } `enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list-->node 0-->node 1-->node 2-->NULL

Starting condition:
temp = node 0
curr = node 0
ndex = 2
First iteration of the for loop:
i = 0, 0 <= 2
temp != NULL, assign temp = node 0->next (node 1)
Second iteration:
i = 1, 1 <= 2
temp != NULL, assign temp = node 1->next (node 2)
Third iteration:
i = 2, 2 <= 2
temp != NULL, assign temp = node 2->next (NULL)
Post-loop operations:
assign curr = temp (NULL)
assign temp = temp->next (dereferences NULL pointer and crashes)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void InsertAtNth(int data, int position){
            NodeS newNode = new NodeS(data);
            NodeS temp = head1;
            NodeS prev = null;
            if(head1 == null ){
                head1 = newNode;
            }
            else if(position == 0){
                  newNode.next = head1;
                  head1 = newNode;
              }

            else{
                for(int i = 0;i < position; i++){
                    prev = temp;
                    temp = temp.next;
                }
                prev.next = newNode;
                newNode.next = temp;

            }
        }
```

Comment: if you have any doubts..Please ping